# Adding JList to show basic DB information

Tags: java, database, jlist

My goal is to put a JList with the data from my DB over the 2 JTextFields, but i dont know how to do it. Do you guys and girls know what the mistake is and how I can fix it?
(The Variable personList has all the Data in it. Just need to put it in JList. But this Variable personList is a ArrayList.)

```
public class Datenbank2 extends JFrame {

public Datenbank2() {
    super("Datenbank der Lehrlinge 1 Lehrjahr");

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel linkesPanel = new JPanel();

    this.setBounds(600, 300, 500, 450);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://Users/N-YP/workspace/UebungJava/ch/nyp/uebungen/datenbanken/SqLiteDB.db");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Person");

        ArrayList<JLabel> personList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String vorname = rs.getString("Vorname");
            String nachname = rs.getString("Nachname");
            personList.add(new JLabel(vorname + " " + nachname));
            System.out.println(vorname + "  " + nachname);
        }


        JTextField eingVorname = new JTextField();
        JTextField eingNachname = new JTextField();
        eingVorname.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230, 30));
        eingNachname.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230, 30));

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(borderLayout);

        this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        centerPanel.add(linkesPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();

        centerPanel.setLayout(flowLayout);
        for (JLabel personLabel : personList) {
            centerPanel.add(personLabel);
        }

        southPanel.setLayout(flowLayout);
        southPanel.add(eingVorname);
        southPanel.add(eingNachname);
    }

    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
        System.out
                .println("Datenbank geöffnet (muss später aber wieder geschlossen werden).");

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Datenbank2 javamitdb = new Datenbank2();
    javamitdb.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Thank you and have a nice Day.

Comment: How about using a jlist ? In the supplied code you add labels to a panel. You can find more info as well as examples on jlists in the javadocs : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Comment: @Grims  I did find the webside helfull but i think they dont have anything with ArrayListy<JLable>. So I gone read some more on there

Comment: You have a mistake (so...what is it?) or you don't know how to do something?

Comment: @Poldie My goal is to put a JList with the data from my DB over the 2 JTextFields, but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: If you look at the description of arraylist and vector, you'll notice they share the same interfaces as well as parent classes. In fact you can't just replace the one with the other. The reason jlist's constructor expects a vector and not an arraylist is because vector is synchronised (thread safe). Also you can use new JList(yourArrayList.toArray())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well use [**DefaultListModel**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) and its **addElement() method** in your while loop to add each result, like the following:

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
while (rs.next()) {
        String vorname = rs.getString("Vorname");
        String nachname = rs.getString("Nachname");
        listModel.addElement(vorname + " " + nachname);
        System.out.println(vorname + "  " + nachname);
    }
//then create a list with this model
list = new JList(listModel);
```

Take a look at [**How to Use Lists**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for further information.